# Excel Query If Two Columns contain the same value return a corresponding value from the third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Day

Any help gratefully received I'm a bit overwhelmed with all of the information on here!

I have a workbook holding e-mail addresses and training dates. I need the assignment numbers for the e-mail addresses.

I have exported a list of e-mail addresses and their corresponding assignment numbers.

So in Column A I have a list of reference numbers, in column B I have a list of their associated e-mail addresses. In column D I have a list of e-mail addresses (the adjacent columns have dates they attended specific training). I left column C blank as I thought this is where I would need to type the formula.

I need a formula to see whether the e-mail addresses in column B has a match in column D, and if they do to fill in the corresponding reference number (Column A) in column C (adjacent to the correct e-mail address in column D).

Thank you to anyone who can assist in any way.

Regards

Stuart

I have tried Index, Match, If and Kutools, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but I think you might be looking for XLOOKUP or VLOOKUP?

In this example the formula in B2 is

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,$F$1:$F$8,$G$1:$G$8)
```

If you have an older version of excel you could use instead

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$1:$G$8,2,FALSE)
```

[image]